# Using @BeforeAll to instantiate an object in JUnit returns null

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit, junit5

This seems easy and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm using the @BeforeAll tag to create a new Sequence object and use that instance in each test method. However, it seems that the Sequence object is null and I don't understand why. I made sure that the @BeforeAll method is static.

```java
public class SequenceTest {
    static Sequence seq;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void createTestSequence() {

        seq =  new Sequence();
        assertEquals(null, seq);  // this passes when it shouldn't!
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        // do test 
        // fails because Sequence object is null
    }
}
```

I'm using maven and I included these dependencies in my pom.xml file:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
</plugin>

<!-- junit 5, unit test -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Could you add the whole code? Here the ```@BeforeAll``` is actually missing! Are you sure also that you are using JUnit5? Try debugging and see if you are entering the beforeAll method. I feel you are mixing JUnit4 and JUnit5 annotations. In fact: @BeforeEach and @BeforeAll are the JUnit 5 equivalents of @Before and @BeforeClass.

Comment: You are not using `@BeforeAll`, is `sr` a static variable ?l

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy the code correctly. Can u look at it now :)? Thanks!

Comment: You are using not `BeforeAll` you are using `@Before` which is JUnit 4. So your imports are wrong. Furthermore you are using a too old version of maven-surefire-plugin at least 2.22.2 and add `junit-jupiter-api` as dependency and a more recent version of JUnit Jupiter....If you like to initialize a variable for all tests in JUnit Jupiter you should use `@BeforeEach`...

Comment: Thank you it works now!!  I was using old junit and surefire dependencies. I changed to most recent version and the issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your block code should work. Maybe your maven fire plugin does not run any test? I've tried with following block code and the test failed:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;


import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class SequenceTest {
    static Sequence seq;

    @BeforeAll
    static void createTestSequence() {

        seq =  new Sequence();
        assertEquals(null, seq);  // this passes when it shouldn't!
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        // do test
        // fails because Sequence object is null
    }
}

class Sequence{

}
```

I've got following error:

> expected:  but was: org.tdd.others.Sequence@9b7af25
> org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected:  but was:
> org.tdd.others.Sequence@9b7af25     at
> org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)     at
> org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:182)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:177)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:1124)
> at
> org.tdd.others.SequenceTest.createTestSequence(SequenceTest.java:16)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

I was using old dependencies. Changed it to this:

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>

       <!-- junit 5, unit test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```